# A non-constructive flag declined on a non-constructive post

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags, not-constructive

I flagged the question https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/175204/212576 as a *Non constructive* one at ~3 AM IST(**2013-04-04 20:40:46Z**). It was declined by a moderator; yet, the post/question was closed 2 hours after the flag.

[image: me gusta]
<sub>Flag</sub>

Why/who would be declining a legit flag :|

Comment: Maybe the moderator disagreed that your flag was legit? Flagging on meta is like asking questions; it's dangerous. There are so many high rep users and mods/employees floating around anyway that most things get dealt with quickly anyway; no mod/employee voted to close this question.

Answer (score 5):

I agree the question is "not constructive" (and possibly outright trolling) and just casted the last delete vote.

I also agree with the moderator that declined the flag, there wasn't really *any* reason for moderation intervention there. The question was getting buried with downvotes, and it was obvious that it had already received moderation attention, two diamonds had commented on it minutes after it appeared. What's the point of flagging it?

Lastly, keep in mind that this is Meta. Do we *really* want moderators quickly closing down "not constructive" discussions? Would there anything be left open if they did?

Comment: @Bart I'm saying that when you cast a flag, you are asking someone to take some time and do something for you. Use your common sense and only do that when there's a real reason. I don't have any reason to doubt hjpotter92 thought there was a real reason for flagging at the time, but if he did, I disagree with him.

Comment: Ah damn, just removed my comment. The edits to your answer clarified it for me. Thanks.

Comment: @Yannis Excellent point. We need the guy from 300 with a sign that says, "THIS IS META".  Moderating on meta is enough to make a grown man cry.